# Implement AES algorithm with CUDA

Tags: algorithm, cuda, aes

The most important problem of AES algorithm is its low speed.

Is it possible to implement its algorithm with CUDA ? I know it's possible but I know how much can I improve it's speed ?

Comment: You should follow the design principles supplied by the authors of AES. BTW, I am surprised to see AES being qualified as _low speed_ whereas it was designed to meet performance requirements !

Comment: You may find these references useful: - [AES vs. CUDA AES](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BVO97kXuiro) - this video shows a significant difference between both. - [Chapter 36. AES Encryption and Decryption on the GPU](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/gpugems3/part-vi-gpu-computing/chapter-36-aes-encryption-and-decryption-gpu)

Comment: When it comes to dealing with short integers, CUDA hardware generally has difficulty competing with CPUs, if SIMD integer operations (SSE2, AVX2) can be brought to bear, as it can with AES.  The Achilles' heel of AES on CPUs was doing the S-box lookup, because there was no SIMD instruction to throw each byte in an XMM register through a 256-entry lookup table.  The AES-NI instruction set extensions address that deficiency.  So I would expect an AES-NI capable chip to outperform a CUDA chip, and Shane Cook's CUDA book includes a case study that came to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. According to [this article](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=5695236), the speedup can be quite significant.

> There are over 10 times difference of performance by the kind of best
>   GPU implementation which achieved 35.2Gbps throughput and 28.39 fold
>   speed up compared with Core i7-920 2.66GHz CPU implementation.

There is also an opensource implementation with some [interesting benchmarks](http://code.google.com/p/engine-cuda/wiki/benchmarkVersion011).